# Prove that $L=\{a^n b^l : n \leq l\}$ is not regular by pumping lemma

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

I'm currently trying to prove that $L=\{a^n b^l : n \leq l\}$ is not regular by pumping lemma

My proof:

If we choose $w$ such that $w=a^P b^P$, then since $|xy| \leq p$, $y$ must be $a^P$, meaning it can be pumped any number of times $i$, such that $a^{iP} b^P \in L$. Since $iP \leq P$ is not true for any $i > 1$, it cannot exist in $L$, therefore $L$ cannot be regular.

Is this a valid proof? I don't fully comprehend the pumping lemma, so please let me know if/where I may be going wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Crosspost with this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150554/prove-that-l-an-bl-n-leq-l-is-not-regular-by-pumping-lemma) on cs.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect. First, you should start by saying something like: "Suppose that $L$ is regular.
Then, by the pumping lemma, it admits a pumping length, say $P$".

Next, there seems to be a typo, since you use $P$ and $p$. But more importantly, the condition $|xy| \leqslant P$ does not imply $y = a^P$, as you claim.